# Covariance casting with generics

Tags: java, generics, casting

In Java, if I have the following information: `List.class, Map.class, Integer.class`, and an instance `foo` of some Object. Is it possible to cast `foo` into `List<Map<Integer, Integer>>`? I suppose not due to type erasure, but wondering if there is another way to achieve something similar.

EDIT: To provide more context. I'm writing an application that is able to take a query (which is composed of an object and a metric) and outputs the desired metric. An example would be "the sum of the elements in a list". The client would need to write a provider that registers itself to the app and broadcasts that it is able to provide a certain metric type for some object type (e.g. sum for a list). The app, upon receiving the query will match up the correct provider and invoke the `calculate` method on it.

Without generics this is simple. The canonical type for any instance of an object is its class. So I would treat the objects in the query as an `Object` then using its `class`, find a provider that is able to provide for this instance of the object. Similar thing for metrics.

Now introducing generics...Suppose I define my metric `f` to be the sum of elements in a list if the elements are `Integer` and the product if the elements are `Double`. I would need 2 providers one that provides for `List<Integer>` and the other for `List<Double>`. But due to type erasure I cannot use the canonical type `class` directly. So I store the involved classes (`List.class` and `Integer.class` or `List.class` and `Double.class`) and match up the provider using tuples of classes.

Hence in the `calculate` method I need to perform a covariant cast from `Object` to the appropriate type that the provider handles.

Perhaps I'm taking the wrong approach to the problem?

Comment: It is unclear if you mean you know as you are writing the code that it's List, Map, and Integer, in which case you can just do a regular old cast, or if it's three `Class<?>` objects you don't know, in which case you are correct, it is impossible.

Comment: Please provide more coontext. Who creates the instance `List<Map<Integer, Integer>>`? If you control  the `new` statement, you may be able to put additional info there, so that this kind of casting is possible. Do you control it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you'll get is this:

```
List<Map<Integer, Integer>> fooList = List.class.cast(foo);
```

It will produce a Compiler Warning because of unsafe casting and usage of raw types, but it is actually safe (if you know your Object to contain what it says it does).

Comment: But there is no advantage over "traditional" casting in this case, or is there?

Comment: No, you'd use this version if you didn't have the type at compile time

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd thx, I was actually doing exactly what you mentioned. Didn't like the compiler warning so was wondering if there was some other way to do this that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Not without getting a warning, AFAIK.

```
List<Map<Integer, Integer>> bar = (List<Map<Integer, Integer>>) foo;
```